# setting disabled property on multiple controls at once

Tags: html, jsf, xpages

I want to steer the disabled property for different types of controls (edit box, combo lists, text area, ...) at once and not per control.

Is this possible and how?

On a theme you can compute the property of a control e.g.

```
<property>
    <name>pageTitle</name>
    <value>#{javascript:@DbTitle()}</value>
 </property>
```

But in my application I have different types of objects managed via different beans (e.g. order/orderbean, customer/customerbean) so I doubt I can set it via the theme?

I am not sure if I can set it "temporarily" for a specific xpage via the FacesContext?

Comment: Is http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute what are looking for?

Comment: I am working within XPages , that is IBMäs implementation of JSF for IBM Domino where I do not think to have that attribute available :-/

Comment: Omnifaces is for JSF. You tagged the question jsf. if xpages is not jsf, please remove that tag. If it is jsf, you can install omnifaces and have this functionality.

Comment: How about wrapping all the controls in an `xp:panel` and setting the `disabled` property on that?

Comment: hi Mark, I probably never used that capability :-) In my case (of course) the customer does not want all controls locked but most of them. Well that is a something I have to take with me in the design (yes, we are in Acceptance phase when they come with the request) and I also have some controls supported by select2 so some piece of redesign is required to use the approach you mention. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to compute the value and point to a Boolean scope variable. viewScope.somevar.

You change the value of the scope variable and all controls update accordingly

Other option: if the components are together: pack them in a panel and compute its visibility

Comment: disabled != invisible.

Comment: You can compute both